# wso2is-5.3.0 wso2am-2.1.0 sso working but application token re-generation fails

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm following this tutorial in order to enable SSO between wso2is-5.3.0 and wso2am-2.1.0. 
I successfully could perform SSO between carbon, store and publisher of wso2am components.
I do verified that the registry are shared (tested both with mysql and with postgresql backend). There is the blue arrow.

My current pb is that once I connect to the store of api manager, I could create an Application, then i could generate the Keys for this application. BUT, if i do refresh the page or reladed again, the generated credentials are not shown any more and I'm asked to clear the situation(Keys are partially generated)... if i click the only available button, to fix the situation I do receive a very long exception, saying that

```
    [2017-04-24 00:36:42,894] ERROR - application:jag "tiers" is not defined.
    [2017-04-24 00:36:45,932] DEBUG - subscription-list:jag getSubscriptions : []
    [2017-04-24 00:36:48,623] ERROR - AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Can not create OAuth application  : gw03_PRODUCTION
    org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:2418)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:62)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:110)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:139)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118)
           ....


            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:2418)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:62)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:110)
            ... 78 more
    [2017-04-24 00:36:48,629] ERROR - ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor Error occurred when updating the status of the Application creation process
    org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1269)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:155)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2789)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:385)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
            at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c2._c_anonymous_2(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:39)
            .....

            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : gw03_PRODUCTION
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.handleException(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:639)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:112)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:139)
            ... 77 more
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:2418)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:62)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:110)
            ... 78 more
    [2017-04-24 00:36:48,631] ERROR - APIConsumerImpl Could not execute Workflow
    org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred when updating the status of the Application creation process
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:82)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2789)
            at ...... 
 org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78)
            ... 75 more
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : gw03_PRODUCTION
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.handleException(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:639)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:112)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:139)
            ... 77 more
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:2418)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:62)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:110)
            ... 78 more
    [2017-04-24 00:36:48,632] ERROR - APIStoreHostObject Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:gw03
    org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Could not execute Workflow
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2814)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:385)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
            at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c2._c_anonymous_2(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:39)
            at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c2.call(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
            at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0._c_anonymous_10(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag:35)
            at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0.call(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
            at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:240)
            at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
            at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
            at ..... 
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : gw03_PRODUCTION
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.handleException(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:639)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:112)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:139)
            ... 77 more
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException: APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceAPIManagementException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:2418)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:62)
            at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:110)
            ... 78 more
```

The problem appears with both postgres and mysql so maybe there is a pb in the config files, but any advice is welcomed !

Answer (score 0):

The product is working correctly for SSO btw wso2am2.1.0 and wso2ids5.3.0 with these settings :

- Mysql backend
- Use the pre packaged wos2is for sso with wso2am
- Stricly following the documentation ....

Thx wso2.